# Generics method not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, generics

I have a `Node<T>` (inner) class in `Graph<T>` class:

```
public class Graph<T> {
    private ArrayList<Node<T>> vertices;
    public boolean addVertex(Node<T> n) {
        this.vertices.add(n);
        return true;
    }
    private class Node<T> {...}
}
```

When I run this:

```
Graph<Integer> g = new Graph<Integer>();
Node<Integer> n0 = new Node<>(0);
g.addVertex(n0);
```

The last line give me error:

```
The method addVertice(Graph<Integer>.Node<Integer>) in the type Graph<Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (Graph<T>.Node<Integer>)
```

Why? Thanks in advance?

Comment: What language? I'm guessing C# but there might be others with the same (or similar) syntax.

Comment: Where have you defined addVertice? we cannot see it in the example.

Comment: You should make the `Node` class `static`.

Comment: @astander I've reedited the code. Sorry for mistake ><

Comment: @ RC. it works! but what's the reason?

Comment: That's because you need an object of outer class to create an object of inner class if it's not static.

Comment: Read book on the difference between different inner classes.

Comment: The reason is if an inner class is not static, you can only create an object of it using the enclosing instance of the outer class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner class should not override `T` Since `T` is already used in outerclass. Consider what can happen if it was allowed. Your outer class would have referred to `Integer` and Inner class would have referred to another class that too for the same instance.

```
 public boolean addEdge(Node node1, Node node2) {
        return false;
    }

    Graph<Integer> g = new Graph<Integer>();
    Graph<Integer>.Node n0 = g.new Node(0);// As T happens to be integer you can use inside node class also.

    public class Node {
        T t;
        Node(T t) {
        }
    }
```

Or you can use `Static Inner class` since Static Generics Types are different than instance generic types.

For More Explanation you can Refer to [JLS # 4.8. Raw Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html)

Answer (score 1):

Following code works fine for me. Running on JRE 1.6

```
public class Generic<T> {
    private ArrayList<Node<T>> vertices = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();

    public boolean addVertice(Node<T> n) {
        this.vertices.add(n);
        System.out.println("added");
        return true;
    }


    public static class Node<T> {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Generic<Integer> g = new Generic<Integer>();
        Node<Integer> n0 = new Node<Integer>();
        g.addVertice(n0);
    }


}
```